# JavaFX builders/Java Generics

Tags: generics, javafx-2

I want to re-use a Builder instance to create several controls but I'm getting compile errors which I don't understand. I think they're caused by me not understanding generics properly. Can anyone help?

```
ButtonBuilder builder = ButtonBuilder.create().minHeight(40.0).minWidth(40.0);
Button button1 = builder.onAction(clickHandler).build(); // Error
Button button2 = ButtonBuilder.create().minHeight(40.0).minWidth(40.0).onAction(clickHandler).build(); //OK
```

where clickHandler is a `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`

The error I get is

```
error: cannot find symbol
    Button button1 = builder.onAction(clickHandler).build();
                                                   ^
symbol:   method build()
location: class ButtonBaseBuilder
```

ButtonBaseBuilder implements Builder so it should have a build() method, shouldn't it? Also if I run everything together (as in button2) it is OK.

This is on JDK 7.0u4 and JavaFX SDK 2.1

Thanks in advance,
Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass ButtonBuilder generic parameter to use builders that way:

```
    ButtonBuilder<? extends ButtonBuilder> builder =
                     ButtonBuilder.create().minHeight(40.0).minWidth(40.0);
    Button button1 = builder.onAction(clickHandler).build();
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand; adding the generic parameter to the type of ButtonBuilder tells the compiler to 'remember' its type (by inference) - without it, the XXXBuilder methods return their own type which is a superclass of ButtonBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

`ButtonBaseBuilder` does not have a `build` method. `ButtonBuilder`, which `extends ButtonBaseBuilder`, has one because it `implements Builder<Button>`.

This should work:

```
Button button1 = ((ButtonBuilder) builder.onAction(clickHandler)).build();
```

Comment: OK, yes I missed that first time around. The builders are in a hierarchy and just the 'tips' implement Build<>